# How to display string from LPVOID type in Edit control

Tags: c++, winapi

I have problem when using File Mapping and read it.

Bellow code, i get pMemory form MapViewOfFile, but I don't know how to display content to Edit control, I only get mess characters (like Chinese characters). I want to use UNICODE

```
szFileName = L"abc.txt";
hFile = CreateFile(szFileName, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE, NULL);
hMapFile = CreateFileMapping(hFile, NULL, PAGE_READONLY, 0, 0, NULL);

pMemory = MapViewOfFile(hMapFile, FILE_MAP_READ, 0,0,0);
FileSize = GetFileSize(hFile, NULL);
SendMessage(hWndEdit, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)(LPCWSTR)pMemory);
UnmapViewOfFile(pMemory);
CloseHandle(hMapFile);
CloseHandle(hFile);
```

Anyone can help me ???

**UPDATE:**
I've debugged pMemory and sure it contain address. And when I use file with only ASCII text + use SendMessageA --> it work pretty fine, display correct text (but only not separate line). But if I use text with UNICODE text, it don't display correct characters

Comment: Well, are you sure your file contains UNICODE text?!

Comment: @Adriano, agreed.. there's a *lot* going on here to just set some text from a file...

Comment: yes, it contain UNICODE text

Comment: Examine the memory at pMemory with the debugger. Figure out whether the memory contains a pointer (won't work) or ASCII text or unicode text.

Comment: I debugged pMemory and sure it work correct (have address)

Comment: If you're sure it contains Unicode text, are you *sure* it contains a Unicode **terminator** ? Without one this will easily fall off the deep end of pulling in data past end-of-buffer and into undefined behavior. For `WM_SETTEXT` the `lParam` parameter must be, per the documentation, "A pointer to a null-terminated string that is the window text".

Comment: You need to know the encoding of the text file. If it's not UTF-16 you can't send it directly to the control, you need to decode it first. I'm guessing it's UTF-8.

Comment: According to your update: **are you sure it contains Unicode text with encoding required for LPWSTR**? It **must** be UTF-16 (so other Unicode encodings - UTF7, UTF-8, UTF-32, big enddian UTF-16 - aren't allowed).

Comment: Edit your question and show us the let's say 100 first bytes that pMemory points to.

Comment: @Adriano, how can I test what pMemory contain encoding ? (plz tell me step by step because I not good in debug yet). And second, What I need to do to match encoding 2 side ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz, data that pMemory point to here: ef bb bf 63 e1 bb 99 6e 67 20 68 c3 a2 6e 20 61 62 63 0d 0a 64 65 66 67 68 69 0d 0a 31 32 33 34 35 36 00 00 ...(ï»¿cá»™ng hÃ¢n abc..defghi..123)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, your file have not have UTF-16 encoded, but your Edit control is using UTF-16.
You can use MultiByteToWideChar to convert UTF-8 to UTF-16.

Note that use MultiByteToWideChar you need call 2 times, example:

```
int size_needed = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, (LPCCH)pMemory, -1, NULL, 0);
wchar_t *buffer = new wchar_t[size_needed];
MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, (LPCCH)pMemory, -1, buffer, size_needed);
```

First time is get size needed to convert and Second is put into wide string. See more: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Your code can be edited:

```
szFileName = L"abc.txt";
hFile = CreateFile(szFileName, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE, NULL);
hMapFile = CreateFileMapping(hFile, NULL, PAGE_READONLY, 0, 0, NULL);
pMemory = MapViewOfFile(hMapFile, FILE_MAP_READ, 0,0,0);

int size_needed = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, (LPCCH)pMemory, -1, NULL, 0);
wchar_t *buffer = new wchar_t[size_needed];
MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, (LPCCH)pMemory, -1, buffer, size_needed);

FileSize = GetFileSize(hFile, NULL);
SendMessage(hWndEdit, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)buffer);
delete[] buffer;
UnmapViewOfFile(pMemory);
CloseHandle(hMapFile);
CloseHandle(hFile);
```

Comment: Greate  ! It work ! Thank you. But, I still don't understand first  MultiByteToWideChar ?

Comment: Like the answer says, the first call is used to just calculate the size of the UTF-16 buffer (by specifying NULL for the output buffer), then the buffer is allocated to that size and passed to the second call which fills the buffer with the actual UTF-16 data.  This kind of usage is typical of many Windows API functions that return dynamic-sized data. However, there is a minor bug in this code - using -1 at the input size requires the input data to be null-terminated, which this code is not guaranteeing.

Comment: You should call `GetFileSize()` first, pass that value as the input length to `MultiByteToWideChar()`, then make sure the output data is null-terminated before passing it to `WM_SETTEXT`, which requires a null-terminated string.

Answer (score 3):

If your file data is not UTF-16 encoded, but your Edit window is using UTF-16 (because it was registered with `RegisterClassW()` or `RegisterClassExW()`), then you must either:

1. convert the file data to UTF-16 yourself using `MultiByteToWideChar()` (or equivalent) and then use `SendMessageW()` to send `WM_SETTEXT`.
2. use `SendMessageA()` to send `WM_SETTEXT` and let the OS convert the data to UTF-16 for you using the OS's default Ansi codepage (this only works if the file data matches the OS's default encoding).

If your file data is UTF-16 encoded, but your Edit window is not using UTF-16 (because it was registered with `RegisterClassA()` or `RegisterclassExA()`), then you must either:

1. convert the file data to Ansi yourself using `WideCharToMultiByte()` (or equivalent) and then use `SendMessageA()` to send `WM_SETTEXT`.
2. use `SendMessageW()` to send `WM_SETTEXT` and let the OS convert the data to Ansi for you using the OS's default Ansi codepage.

If your file data is UTF-16 encoded and your Edit window is using UTF-16, or if your file data is Ansi encoded and your Edit window is using Ansi and the encodings match, then you can use the generic `SendMessage()` to send `WM_SETTEXT` passing the data as-is without needing to do any conversions.

You can use `IsWindowUnicode()` to know whether the Edit window is using Ansi or UTF-16.  As for the file data, you could try using `IsTextUnicode()`, but that is known to report false results, so you really should not rely on it.  Know what your file encoding is ahead of time and code for that, or else prompt the user for the file encoding.

Comment: +1 Comprehensive but there is **also encoding issues** (for example UTF-8 encoded file can't be directly used with an Unicode window which expects UTF-16).

Comment: @Andriano: that would fall into the "Ansi file and Unicode window" portion of my answer. `MultiByteToWideChar()` can decode UTF-8 to UTF-16, by specifying the `CP_UTF8` codepage. Same with any other Ansi encoding that is installed in the OS. Or use a third-party library, like iconv or icu, which implement more encodings.

Comment: Yes, now it's more clear. I just didn't assume he can see that point because he didn't handle it.

Comment: Thank you very much @RemyLebeau, I understand your advise :)